# Fitness data: merging multiple sources data

Tags: android, ios, healthkit, google-fit, hkhealthstore

**Given:**

The App is collecting steps/distance data from proprietary fitness tracker. This data is split into hourly sessions - e.g. "Session 4:00 - 5:00, *XX* steps, *YY* km".

I want to achieve data transfer: App -> Fitness API (**Google Fit**, **Health Kit**) in a consistent manner - that is: if Fitness API already has a session 4:00-5:00 with *ZZ* steps, then the data is to be somehow merged.

Obvious problems arise if we consider the situation: Tracker 1 is bound to App, Tracker 2 is bound to Fitness API directly, and user wears both at the same time. Then the two trackers have intersecting timespans with different data (e.g. *400* steps on *Tracker 1*, *720* steps on *Tracker 2*).

**The questions are:**

1. How do Google Fit/ Health Kit merge data points that have same/intersecting timespan (in my case, 4:00 - 5:00) ? Is it "always add", even if overlapping occurs?
2. Are there any documented approaches on performing such a sync? I would very much welcome any kind of information, even an abstract sync strategy.
3. Is it better to insert "instantaneous" data into Fitness API, instead of manually aggregated (into sessions)? E.g. I receive instantaneous measurement from Tracker, which is always "total steps for the current day", and then give that total to **Google Fit**/**Health Kit**
4. If answer to 3 is "yes", then will Fitness storage automatically split these instants into sessions?

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate the data by

`.aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)`

as described [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#read_detailed_and_aggregate_data)

Comment: Yes I can, but what does it give to me in context of my question?

Comment: `.setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`
As per documentation, it should aggregate the Step counts during this timespan instead of overlapping.

Comment: Ok, that would probably help on the client side. Need to check